# How to control page refresh on Android browsers?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I like to read the news when I take the subway. The problem is that there is no internet connection on the subway, and thus my strategy is to preload in different Chrome tabs all the articles that I'd like to read, and then cross my fingers that when I access the tab in Chrome, it won't try to *stupidly* refresh the page and then give me a "no connection found" page instead of just keeping the pre-loaded page (this is what I call *very dumb*; it seems to me that a properly designed software would not just kill the content of a page when trying to refresh and there is no connection). Sometimes it does not try to refresh the page, sometimes it does -- I have not succeeded to figure out the pattern. Note that I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini with 1.5 GB RAM and so I don't think it is a RAM issue (it also does that even if I just rebooted the phone and have only 2-3 tabs open in Chrome).

In any case, is there any tweak, plug-in, or whatever, I can do in Chrome to be able to prevent it to refresh pages when I don't want to? If not, is there *any* other Android browser that implements this feature (a "do not refresh any page" button or something like that would do)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Chrome, but **UC Browser** is definitely an answer to your question. You can preload the pages and then even if the data connection is off, you can read the articles (in your case). Just make sure you don't kill the app itself.